# how to get time and date value using NTP in stm32?

Tags: stm32, ntp

I want to get RTC value in stm32 using NTP.
I have implemented ESP32 with NTP and getting correct time but I have used NTP client library and donot know how he is getting the value from pool.ntp.Sever.

Comment: NTP requires a network connection to the internet. Does your STM32 have it? If so, please specify what software framework you are using to program the STM32.